# ngOfficeUIFabric or office-ui-fabric-react

Tags: spfx, office-ui-fabric-react, office-ui-fabric

kind of newer on office 365 and SPFX ?

Im tring to use OfficeUIFabric, im in front of two choices : ngOfficeUIFabric or office-ui-fabric-react 
the decision isnt easy, so i need your feedbacks on using those two ?
and which one you prefer ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngOfficeUIFabric uses angular js directives to provide with ready made components.

- using Angular v1.x with TypeScript for building SharePoint Framework
  client-side web parts
- using ngOfficeUIFabric for styling Angular v1.x    client-side web
  parts
- including Angular and ngOfficeUIFabric in the    web part bundle

Whereas office-ui-fabric-react uses react js to provide with ready made components. We had decided to go with office-ui-fabric-react and the components provided are beautiful and responsive.

The comparison should be more of react vs angular js here?

Angular js code directly manipulates DOM whereas react js provides you with a virtual DOM. That said react js comes out to be 5 times faster than Angular js. React focuses on the view part. As web parts are components, react would be the recommended approach for the designing decoupled components. Although it depends on your knowledge of the JavaScript framework, because learning a new languauge requires investment of time. That said learning react has served the purpose for us until now.

Read the blog below for a detailed discussion:

[why-react-js-recommended-framework-developing-client-side](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/why-react-js-recommended-framework-developing-client-side-khan/)